# Style of footer element changes when I refresh the page?

Tags: html, css

I plead with any one reading this, please help me solve this problem I have spent hours trying to figure it out. There is this red line in the footer shown here [image: pic] specifically the red line that sits under the social section in the footer. Note. I made all 3 of these lines the same way except the one that sits under the social section changes position slightly everytime i refresh but the other red lines stay the same?? wtf is happening I can't figure it out

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

nav li a {
 text-decoration-line: none;
 color: rgba(102,102,102,0.75);
}

.wrapper2 {
 width: 100%;
 height: 65vh;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

header {
 background-image: url(../img/pexels.jpg);
 background-position: center;
 background-size: cover;
 height: 65vh;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

header h1 {
 color: white;
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 5rem;
 font-family: 'Arvo';
}

nav {
 background-color: white;
 width: 100%;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 2;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px grey;
}

nav ul {
 margin-right: 30px;
 margin-top: 25px;
}

nav li {
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 1.55rem;
 margin-right: 20px;
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 color: rgba(102,102,102,0.75);
}

nav li a:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 color: #1a1a1a;
 transition: all 0.7s ease;
}

.after:after {
 position: relative;
 left: 12px;
 top: 2px;
 display: inline-block;
 content: "";
 width: 1px;
 height: 20px;
 background-color: rgba(102,102,102,0.25);
}

.logo {
 color: red;
 font-size: 3.7rem;
 margin: 10px;
 opacity: 1;
 margin-left: 30px;
}

/*---ABOUT---*/

.history h2 {
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);
 font-size: 3rem;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.history h2:after {
 content: '';
 width: 18px;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: red;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 13px;
}

.history h2:before {
 content: '';
 width: 18px;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: red;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 13px;
}

.history p {
 color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 font-size: 1.7rem;
 text-align: center;
 width: 90%;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-top: 35px;
 position: relative;
 top: -20px;
}

/*---SERVICES---*/

.services {
 background-image: url(../img/pour.jpeg);
 background-size: cover;
 background-attachment: fixed;
}

.services .wrapper {
 width: 100%;
 height: 250px;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.services {
 color: white;
 font-family: 'Arvo';
 font-size: 3rem;
}

.services .content {
 background-color: white;
 width: 100%;
}

.services h2 {
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);
 font-size: 3rem;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 position: relative;
 top: 20px;
}

.services h2:after {
 content: '';
 width: 18px;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: red;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 13px;
}

.services h2:before {
 content: '';
 width: 18px;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: red;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 13px;
}

.services .list {
 display: flex;
 padding-bottom: -40px;
}

.move-ul {
 position: relative; 
 top: -45px;
}

.services ul {
 flex-basis: 33.333%;
 color: red;
 font-size: 1.8rem;
 display: inline-block;
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 list-style-type: square;
 margin-left: 80px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}

.padding {
 padding-top: 10px;
}

.services p {
 margin: 0;
}

/*---TESTIMONY---*/

.testimony {
 background-image: url('../img/wall4.jpg');
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-around;
 background-attachment: fixed;
}

.testimony h1 {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 margin-top: 20px;
 color: white;
 font-family: 'Arvo';
 padding: 30px;
 display: inline-block;
 flex-basis: 40%;
 margin-left: 30px;
}

.testimony span {
 color: white;
 font-size: 2.3rem;
}

.testimony .quote {
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 margin-left: 40px;
}

.testimony .left-quote {
 position: relative; 
 left: 60px; 
 top: 30px
}

.fa-quote-right {
 position: relative;
 right: 35px;
 top: 30px;
}

.testimony .move {
 right: 68px;
}

/*---FOOTER---*/

.footer .wrapper {
 display: flex;
}

.footer div {
 display: inline-block;
 flex-basis: 33.33%;
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 color: rgba(102,102,102, 1);
 margin-top: 5px;
}

.footer h1 {
 font-size: 2rem;
 margin-top: 15px;
}

.footer .inner {
 margin-left: 55px;
}

.social .inner {
 margin-left: 45px;
}

.contact .inner {
 margin-left: 35px;
}

.footer .inner:before {
 display: inline-block;
 content: '';
 width: 27.1%;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.6);
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 54px;
}


.links .inner:after {
 content: '';
 width: 10.5%;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: red;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: -151px;
}

.social .inner:after {
 content: '';
 width: 5.8%;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: red;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: -147.5px;
}

.contact .inner:after {
 content: '';
 width: 7.5%;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: red;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: -174.5px;
}

.wrap:before {
 content: '';
 width: 100px;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: red;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 55px;
}

.links a {
 display: block;
 text-decoration-line: none;
 color: rgba(102,102,102, 1);
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 position: relative;
 top: -10px;
 transition: color 0.4s ease;
}

.links a:hover {
 color: red;
}

.contact p {
 position: relative;
 top: -10px;
}

.social i {
 font-size: 1.7rem;
 margin-right: 5px;
 position: relative;
 top: -20px;
 color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.7);
 transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.social i:hover {
 color: red;
 cursor: pointer;
}

#msg {
 margin-top: -15px;
}

.footer-textarea {
 background-color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.2);
 outline: none;
 color: rgba(102,102,102, 1);
 resize: none;
 width: 102%;
}

.footer button {
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: 15.85%;
 margin-top: -18px;
 border: none;
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 transition: all ease 0.4s;
 outline: none;
}

button:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 color: red;
}

.dark {
 color: red;
}

.copyright {
 position: absolute;
 background-color: white;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 padding-bottom: 4px;
}



/*-------MEDIA QUERIES-------*/



/*---TABLET-LARGE---*/

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {

 /*---FOOTER---*/
 
 .footer .inner {
  margin-left: 30px;
 }

 .footer-textarea {
  width: 88%;
 }

 .footer button {
  margin-left: 22.25%;
 }

 .social .inner:after {
  width: 7.8%;
  margin-top: -80px;
  left: 36.25%;
 }

 .links .inner:after {
  width: 14%;
 }

 .contact .inner:after {
  width: 10%;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 823px) {

 /*---MAIN---*/

 header, .wrapper2 {
  height: 100vh;
 }

}

/*---TABLET---*/

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

 /*---NAV---*/

 nav li {
  font-size: 1.55rem;
 }

 nav ul {
  margin-left: 0;
 }

 /*---MAIN--*/

 header {
  height: 65vh;
 }

 .wrapper2 {
  height: 65vh;
 }

 .services ul {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin-left: 30px;
 }

 .padding2 {
  padding-top: 10px;
 }

 .testimony h1 {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
 }


 .testimony .fa-quote-right {
  display: none;
 }

 /*---FOOTER---*/

 .footer .inner {
  margin-left: 30px;
 }

 .links .inner:after {
  width: 18%;
 }

 .contact .inner:after {
  margin-top: -195px;
  width: 13%;
 }

 .social .inner:after {
  left: 37.25%;
  margin-top: -80px;
  width: 10%;
 }

 .footer button {
  margin-left: 20%;
 }

 .footer-textarea {
  width: 88.5%;
 }
}

/*------LANDSCAPE-MODE-MOBILE------*/

@media screen and (max-width: 715px) {
 
 /*---NAV---*/

 nav ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 0;
 }

 nav li {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
 }

 nav .logo {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
 }

 /*---MAIN---*/

 header {
  height: 100vh;
 }

 .wrapper2 {
  height: 100vh;
 }

 .history p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
 }

 .testimony {
  flex-direction: column;
 }

 .testimony h1 {
  margin: 0;
 }

 .move-quote {
  position: relative;
  top: -30px;
 }

 .fa-quote-right {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
 }

 /*---FOOTER---*/

 .contact .inner {
  margin-right: 15px;
 }

 .contact .inner:after {
  margin-top: -171.5px; 
  width: 14%
 }

 .social .inner:after {
  width: 11%
 }

 .links .inner:after {
  width: 20%
 }

 .contact p {
  margin: 5px;
 }

 .footer-textarea {
  position: relative;
  top: -15px;
 }

 .footer button {
  margin-top: -70px;
  margin-left: 19.5%;
 }
}

/*---MOBILE---*/

@media screen and (max-width: 425px) {

 /*---NAV---*/

 .logo {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  margin-left: 10px;
 }

 ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }

 nav li {
  display: none;
 }

 .ham-menu {
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 4px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
 }

 .m1, .m2, .m3 {
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 4px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
 }

 /*---MAIN---*/

 header .wrapper2 {
  height: 60vh;
 }

 header {
  height: 50vh;
  background-position: -370px;
 }

 header h1 {
  font-size: 4rem;
 }

 .history h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
 }

 .history h2:before, .history h2:after {
  margin-bottom: 11px;
 }

 .history p {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
 }

 .services h1 {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
 }

 .services h2 {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  top: 5px;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
 }

 .services h2:before, .services h2:after {
  margin-bottom: 11px;
 }

 .move-ul {
  top: 0;
 }

 .padding {
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
 }

 .services .list {
  flex-direction: column;
 }

 .testimony {
  flex-direction: column;
 }

 .testimony h1 {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  margin-left: 0;
 }

 .move-quote {
  margin-top: -50px;
 }

 .fa-quote-right {
  left: -100px;
 }

 /*---FOOTER---*/

 .footer .wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
 }

 .footer div {
  margin: 0;
 }

 .footer h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-top: 10px;
 }

 .footer .inner {
  margin: 0;
 }

 .footer .inner:before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.6);
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 48px;
 }

 .links .inner:after {
  width: 33%;
  margin-top: -152px;
 }

 .social .inner {
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
 }

 .social .inner:after {
  content: '';
  width: 18%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: -43.75px;
 }

 .contact .inner:after {
  content: '';
  width: 24%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -148px;
 }

 .links a {
  margin-left: 5px;
 }

 .social h1 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
 }

 #msg {
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-right: 25.5%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 80px;
 }

 .footer button {
  right: 9.25%;
  margin-top: 0.2px;
 }

 .social i {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  margin-right: 2px;
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  left: 5px;
  color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.7);
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
 }

 .footer-textarea {
  width: 88.5%;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 5px;
 }

 .contact p {
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
 }

 .copyright {
  background-color: red;
 }

 .copyright span {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
 }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {

 /*---FOOTER---*/

 .links .inner:after {
  width: 37%;
 }

 .social .inner:after {
  margin-top: -38px;
  width: 20%;
 }

 .contact .inner:after {
  width: 27%;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 325px) {
 .social .inner: after {
  margin-top: -39px;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intitial-scale=1.0">
 <title>About | Kane Concrete & Construction</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/about.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo|Bitter|Lato|Montserrat|Noto+Sans|Open+Sans|Poppins|Roboto|Sarabun|Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel|Asap|Krub|Oxygen|Rajdhani|Staatliches|Varela+Round" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <div class="wrapper2">
   <nav>
    <div class="logo">
     <i class="fab fa-accusoft"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="nav">
     <div class="ham-menu">
      <div class="m1"></div>
      <div class="m2"></div>
      <div class="m3"></div>
     </div>
     <ul>
      <li class="after"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li class="after"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li class="after"><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
      <li class="after"><a href="careers.html">Careers</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </nav>
   <h1>About Us</h1>
  </div>
 </header>

 <section class="history" style="background-color: white;">
  <h2>Our History</h2>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat ea magni suscipit modi sapiente. Perferendis odit, incidunt, amet adipisci, quaerat aperiam, impedit nemo excepturi culpa quis libero nostrum molestiae error eveniet ipsa repellat? Cum quae laudantium totam neque provident fuga rerum quasi dolorum vel obcaecati quidem perspiciatis iure maiores dignissimos, recusandae enim error libero nobis inventore quo adipisci perferendis. Pariatur.</p>
 </section>

 <section class="services" id="services">
  <div class="wrapper">
   <h1>Services</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
   <h2>Our skills</h2>

   <div class="list">
    <ul class="skills move-ul padding2">
     <li><p style="color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);">Flatwork Concrete</p></li>
     <li><p style="color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);">Paving</p></li>
     <li><p style="color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);">Driveways</p></li>
     <li><p style="color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);">Sidewalks</p></li>
     <li><p style="color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);">Slab Repair</p></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="skills adjust-height">
     <li><p style="color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);">Foundations</p></li>
     <li><p style="color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);">Flooring</p></li>
     <li><p style="color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);">Seismic Retrofit</p></li>
     <li><p style="color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);">Other Concrete Concerns</p></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="skills move-ul padding">
     <li><p style="color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);">Commercial</p></li>
     <li><p style="color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);">Residential</p></li>
     <li><p style="color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);">Decks and Patios</p></li>
     <li><p style="color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);">Kitchen Flooring</p></li>
     <li><p style="color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);">Curb Repair</p></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>

 <section class="testimony">
  <div class="block">
   <span><i class="fas fa-quote-left left-quote"></i></span><h1 class="first-quote">Most companys that I searched charged way too much, until I found Kane. They were fast, cheap, and very professional. I'm happy I chose them and will definitely keep them in mind for any other of my future projects.<span class="quote">-Some Person</span></h1>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
   <span class="move-quote"><i class="fas fa-quote-left left-quote"></i></span><h1 class="move-quote">I was very impressed with their work. They were cost effective and efficient and overall a good team. Saw a lot of synergy with their organization and others they worked with. They definitely know what they're doing.<span class="quote">-Some Person</span></h1>
  </div>
 </section>

 <section class="footer">
  <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="links">
    <div class="inner">
     <h1>Quick Links</h1>

     <a href="#">Home</a>
     <a href="#">About</a>
     <a href="#">Services</a>
     <a href="#">Job Openings</a>
     <a href="#">Gallery</a>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="social">
    <div class="inner">
     <h1>Social</h1>

     <i class="fab fa-linkedin"><a href="#" class="social-net"></a></i>
     <i class="fab fa-facebook"><a href="#" class="social-net"></a></i>
     <i class="fab fa-twitter-square"><a href="#" class="social-net"></a></i>

     <button name="msg">Send</button>
     <textarea name="msg" class="footer-textarea" cols="45" rows="5" placeholder="Send is some feedback..."></textarea>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="contact">
    <div class="inner" class="wrap">
     <h1>Contact</h1>

     <p>(208)546-7827 - <span class="dark">Matt</span></p>
     <p>(208)546-7827 - <span class="dark">Keegan</span></p>
     <p><span class="dark">Address</span> - P.O. Box 50860 IF, ID 83405</p>
     <p><span class="dark">Email</span> - KaneConcrete@fake.com</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="copyright"><span>&copy; 2019 - Kane Concrete & Construction | ALL RIGHTS RESERVED</span></div>
 </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close. However, by using negative `margin-top` you might get the position inconsistent. To get a more consistent solution, I've wrapped the footer `h1` titles inside a `span` tag. That way, a pseudo-element `:after` was applied to add the red line and positioned relative to just the title.

Basically, *besides the extra span,* the following CSS code was added *(and the unnecessary per link red line CSS was removed)*. Unhide the code snippet and run to see it working. Hope it helps.

```
.footer h1 span {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
}

.footer h1 span:after {
  content: '';
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

nav li a {
 text-decoration-line: none;
 color: rgba(102,102,102,0.75);
}

.wrapper2 {
 width: 100%;
 height: 65vh;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

header {
 background-image: url(../img/pexels.jpg);
 background-position: center;
 background-size: cover;
 height: 65vh;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

header h1 {
 color: white;
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 5rem;
 font-family: 'Arvo';
}

nav {
 background-color: white;
 width: 100%;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 2;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px grey;
}

nav ul {
 margin-right: 30px;
 margin-top: 25px;
}

nav li {
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 1.55rem;
 margin-right: 20px;
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 color: rgba(102,102,102,0.75);
}

nav li a:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 color: #1a1a1a;
 transition: all 0.7s ease;
}

.after:after {
 position: relative;
 left: 12px;
 top: 2px;
 display: inline-block;
 content: "";
 width: 1px;
 height: 20px;
 background-color: rgba(102,102,102,0.25);
}

.logo {
 color: red;
 font-size: 3.7rem;
 margin: 10px;
 opacity: 1;
 margin-left: 30px;
}

/*---ABOUT---*/

.history h2 {
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);
 font-size: 3rem;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.history h2:after {
 content: '';
 width: 18px;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: red;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 13px;
}

.history h2:before {
 content: '';
 width: 18px;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: red;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 13px;
}

.history p {
 color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 font-size: 1.7rem;
 text-align: center;
 width: 90%;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-top: 35px;
 position: relative;
 top: -20px;
}

/*---SERVICES---*/

.services {
 background-image: url(../img/pour.jpeg);
 background-size: cover;
 background-attachment: fixed;
}

.services .wrapper {
 width: 100%;
 height: 250px;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.services {
 color: white;
 font-family: 'Arvo';
 font-size: 3rem;
}

.services .content {
 background-color: white;
 width: 100%;
}

.services h2 {
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);
 font-size: 3rem;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 position: relative;
 top: 20px;
}

.services h2:after {
 content: '';
 width: 18px;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: red;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 13px;
}

.services h2:before {
 content: '';
 width: 18px;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: red;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 13px;
}

.services .list {
 display: flex;
 padding-bottom: -40px;
}

.move-ul {
 position: relative; 
 top: -45px;
}

.services ul {
 flex-basis: 33.333%;
 color: red;
 font-size: 1.8rem;
 display: inline-block;
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 list-style-type: square;
 margin-left: 80px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}

.padding {
 padding-top: 10px;
}

.services p {
 margin: 0;
}

/*---TESTIMONY---*/

.testimony {
 background-image: url('../img/wall4.jpg');
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-around;
 background-attachment: fixed;
}

.testimony h1 {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 margin-top: 20px;
 color: white;
 font-family: 'Arvo';
 padding: 30px;
 display: inline-block;
 flex-basis: 40%;
 margin-left: 30px;
}

.testimony span {
 color: white;
 font-size: 2.3rem;
}

.testimony .quote {
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 margin-left: 40px;
}

.testimony .left-quote {
 position: relative; 
 left: 60px; 
 top: 30px
}

.fa-quote-right {
 position: relative;
 right: 35px;
 top: 30px;
}

.testimony .move {
 right: 68px;
}

/*---FOOTER---*/

.footer .wrapper {
 display: flex;
}

.footer div {
 display: inline-block;
 flex-basis: 33.33%;
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 color: rgba(102,102,102, 1);
 margin-top: 5px;
}

.footer h1 {
 font-size: 2rem;
 margin-top: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.footer h1 span {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
}

.footer h1 span:after {
 content: '';
 height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
 background-color: red;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.footer .inner:before {
 display: inline-block;
 content: '';
 width: 27.1%;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.6);
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 54px;
}

.wrap:before {
 content: '';
 width: 100px;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: red;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 55px;
}

.links a {
 display: block;
 text-decoration-line: none;
 color: rgba(102,102,102, 1);
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 position: relative;
 top: -10px;
 transition: color 0.4s ease;
}

.links a:hover {
 color: red;
}

.contact p {
 position: relative;
 top: -10px;
}

.social i {
 font-size: 1.7rem;
 margin-right: 5px;
 position: relative;
 top: -20px;
 color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.7);
 transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.social i:hover {
 color: red;
 cursor: pointer;
}

#msg {
 margin-top: -15px;
}

.footer-textarea {
 background-color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.2);
 outline: none;
 color: rgba(102,102,102, 1);
 resize: none;
 width: 102%;
}

.footer button {
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: 15.85%;
 margin-top: -18px;
 border: none;
 font-family: 'Rajdhani';
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 transition: all ease 0.4s;
 outline: none;
}

button:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 color: red;
}

.dark {
 color: red;
}

.copyright {
 position: absolute;
 background-color: white;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 padding-bottom: 4px;
}



/*-------MEDIA QUERIES-------*/



/*---TABLET-LARGE---*/

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {

 /*---FOOTER---*/
 
 .footer .inner {
  margin-left: 30px;
 }

 .footer-textarea {
  width: 88%;
 }

 .footer button {
  margin-left: 22.25%;
 }

 .social .inner:after {
  width: 7.8%;
  margin-top: -80px;
  left: 36.25%;
 }

 .links .inner:after {
  width: 14%;
 }

 .contact .inner:after {
  width: 10%;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 823px) {

 /*---MAIN---*/

 header, .wrapper2 {
  height: 100vh;
 }

}

/*---TABLET---*/

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

 /*---NAV---*/

 nav li {
  font-size: 1.55rem;
 }

 nav ul {
  margin-left: 0;
 }

 /*---MAIN--*/

 header {
  height: 65vh;
 }

 .wrapper2 {
  height: 65vh;
 }

 .services ul {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin-left: 30px;
 }

 .padding2 {
  padding-top: 10px;
 }

 .testimony h1 {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
 }


 .testimony .fa-quote-right {
  display: none;
 }

 /*---FOOTER---*/

 .footer .inner {
  margin-left: 30px;
 }

 .links .inner:after {
  width: 18%;
 }

 .contact .inner:after {
  margin-top: -195px;
  width: 13%;
 }

 .social .inner:after {
  left: 37.25%;
  margin-top: -80px;
  width: 10%;
 }

 .footer button {
  margin-left: 20%;
 }

 .footer-textarea {
  width: 88.5%;
 }
}

/*------LANDSCAPE-MODE-MOBILE------*/

@media screen and (max-width: 715px) {
 
 /*---NAV---*/

 nav ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 0;
 }

 nav li {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
 }

 nav .logo {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
 }

 /*---MAIN---*/

 header {
  height: 100vh;
 }

 .wrapper2 {
  height: 100vh;
 }

 .history p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
 }

 .testimony {
  flex-direction: column;
 }

 .testimony h1 {
  margin: 0;
 }

 .move-quote {
  position: relative;
  top: -30px;
 }

 .fa-quote-right {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
 }

 /*---FOOTER---*/

 .contact .inner {
  margin-right: 15px;
 }

 .contact .inner:after {
  margin-top: -171.5px; 
  width: 14%
 }

 .social .inner:after {
  width: 11%
 }

 .links .inner:after {
  width: 20%
 }

 .contact p {
  margin: 5px;
 }

 .footer-textarea {
  position: relative;
  top: -15px;
 }

 .footer button {
  margin-top: -70px;
  margin-left: 19.5%;
 }
}

/*---MOBILE---*/

@media screen and (max-width: 425px) {

 /*---NAV---*/

 .logo {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  margin-left: 10px;
 }

 ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }

 nav li {
  display: none;
 }

 .ham-menu {
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 4px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
 }

 .m1, .m2, .m3 {
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 4px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
 }

 /*---MAIN---*/

 header .wrapper2 {
  height: 60vh;
 }

 header {
  height: 50vh;
  background-position: -370px;
 }

 header h1 {
  font-size: 4rem;
 }

 .history h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
 }

 .history h2:before, .history h2:after {
  margin-bottom: 11px;
 }

 .history p {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
 }

 .services h1 {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
 }

 .services h2 {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  top: 5px;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
 }

 .services h2:before, .services h2:after {
  margin-bottom: 11px;
 }

 .move-ul {
  top: 0;
 }

 .padding {
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
 }

 .services .list {
  flex-direction: column;
 }

 .testimony {
  flex-direction: column;
 }

 .testimony h1 {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  margin-left: 0;
 }

 .move-quote {
  margin-top: -50px;
 }

 .fa-quote-right {
  left: -100px;
 }

 /*---FOOTER---*/

 .footer .wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
 }

 .footer div {
  margin: 0;
 }

 .footer h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-top: 10px;
 }

 .footer .inner {
  margin: 0;
 }

 .footer .inner:before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.6);
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 48px;
 }

 .links .inner:after {
  width: 33%;
  margin-top: -152px;
 }

 .social .inner {
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
 }

 .social .inner:after {
  content: '';
  width: 18%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: -43.75px;
 }

 .contact .inner:after {
  content: '';
  width: 24%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -148px;
 }

 .links a {
  margin-left: 5px;
 }

 .social h1 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
 }

 #msg {
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-right: 25.5%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 80px;
 }

 .footer button {
  right: 9.25%;
  margin-top: 0.2px;
 }

 .social i {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  margin-right: 2px;
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  left: 5px;
  color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.7);
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
 }

 .footer-textarea {
  width: 88.5%;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 5px;
 }

 .contact p {
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
 }

 .copyright {
  background-color: red;
 }

 .copyright span {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
 }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {

 /*---FOOTER---*/

 .links .inner:after {
  width: 37%;
 }

 .social .inner:after {
  margin-top: -38px;
  width: 20%;
 }

 .contact .inner:after {
  width: 27%;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 325px) {
 .social .inner: after {
  margin-top: -39px;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intitial-scale=1.0">
 <title>About | Kane Concrete & Construction</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/about.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo|Bitter|Lato|Montserrat|Noto+Sans|Open+Sans|Poppins|Roboto|Sarabun|Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel|Asap|Krub|Oxygen|Rajdhani|Staatliches|Varela+Round" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <div class="wrapper2">
   <nav>
    <div class="logo">
     <i class="fab fa-accusoft"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="nav">
     <div class="ham-menu">
      <div class="m1"></div>
      <div class="m2"></div>
      <div class="m3"></div>
     </div>
     <ul>
      <li class="after"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li class="after"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li class="after"><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
      <li class="after"><a href="careers.html">Careers</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </nav>
   <h1>About Us</h1>
  </div>
 </header>

 <section class="history" style="background-color: white;">
  <h2>Our History</h2>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat ea magni suscipit modi sapiente. Perferendis odit, incidunt, amet adipisci, quaerat aperiam, impedit nemo excepturi culpa quis libero nostrum molestiae error eveniet ipsa repellat? Cum quae laudantium totam neque provident fuga rerum quasi dolorum vel obcaecati quidem perspiciatis iure maiores dignissimos, recusandae enim error libero nobis inventore quo adipisci perferendis. Pariatur.</p>
 </section>

 <section class="services" id="services">
  <div class="wrapper">
   <h1>Services</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
   <h2>Our skills</h2>

   <div class="list">
    <ul class="skills move-ul padding2">
     <li><p style="color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);">Flatwork Concrete</p></li>
     <li><p style="color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);">Paving</p></li>
     <li><p style="color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);">Driveways</p></li>
     <li><p style="color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);">Sidewalks</p></li>
     <li><p style="color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);">Slab Repair</p></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="skills adjust-height">
     <li><p style="color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);">Foundations</p></li>
     <li><p style="color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);">Flooring</p></li>
     <li><p style="color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);">Seismic Retrofit</p></li>
     <li><p style="color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);">Other Concrete Concerns</p></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="skills move-ul padding">
     <li><p style="color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);">Commercial</p></li>
     <li><p style="color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);">Residential</p></li>
     <li><p style="color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);">Decks and Patios</p></li>
     <li><p style="color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);">Kitchen Flooring</p></li>
     <li><p style="color: rgba(102,102,102, 0.85);">Curb Repair</p></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>

 <section class="testimony">
  <div class="block">
   <span><i class="fas fa-quote-left left-quote"></i></span><h1 class="first-quote">Most companys that I searched charged way too much, until I found Kane. They were fast, cheap, and very professional. I'm happy I chose them and will definitely keep them in mind for any other of my future projects.<span class="quote">-Some Person</span></h1>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
   <span class="move-quote"><i class="fas fa-quote-left left-quote"></i></span><h1 class="move-quote">I was very impressed with their work. They were cost effective and efficient and overall a good team. Saw a lot of synergy with their organization and others they worked with. They definitely know what they're doing.<span class="quote">-Some Person</span></h1>
  </div>
 </section>

 <section class="footer">
  <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="links">
    <div class="inner">
     <h1><span>Quick Links</span></h1>

     <a href="#">Home</a>
     <a href="#">About</a>
     <a href="#">Services</a>
     <a href="#">Job Openings</a>
     <a href="#">Gallery</a>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="social">
    <div class="inner">
     <h1><span>Social</span></h1>

     <i class="fab fa-linkedin"><a href="#" class="social-net"></a></i>
     <i class="fab fa-facebook"><a href="#" class="social-net"></a></i>
     <i class="fab fa-twitter-square"><a href="#" class="social-net"></a></i>

     <button name="msg">Send</button>
     <textarea name="msg" class="footer-textarea" cols="45" rows="5" placeholder="Send is some feedback..."></textarea>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="contact">
    <div class="inner" class="wrap">
     <h1><span>Contact</span></h1>

     <p>(208)546-7827 - <span class="dark">Matt</span></p>
     <p>(208)546-7827 - <span class="dark">Keegan</span></p>
     <p><span class="dark">Address</span> - P.O. Box 50860 IF, ID 83405</p>
     <p><span class="dark">Email</span> - KaneConcrete@fake.com</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="copyright"><span>&copy; 2019 - Kane Concrete & Construction | ALL RIGHTS RESERVED</span></div>
 </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adjust the margin-top at

```
.social .inner:after {
    content: '';
    width: 5.8%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -159.5px;
}
```